# LED light flux over a bacterial plate surface

Tags: calculus, surface-integrals

I am carrying out an experiment, in which I radiate a bacterial plate with an LED above the plate. In the LED datasheet, I have a graph giving me the relative intensity $I_r$ as a function of the angle $\phi$ to the normal of the LED surface. As I understand this, if I measure the flux on a spherical surface with radius $R$ away from the LED, then I will observe the flux behave like $I_r$($\phi$).

The relative flux at 0$^{\circ}$ from the normal to the LED surface is 100% and the relative flux at 10$^{\circ}$ from the normal is 50% etc. All the flux from the LED is within $\pm$45$^{\circ}$ angle from the normal to the LED surface and I know the total radiant flux (power) $P$ from the LED.

I want to calculate the radiant intensity (flux per unit area) at the bacterial plate, which is located distance $h$ from the LED surface, the LED being located at the center of the bacterial plate horizontally. I know I have to use surface integrals but my calculus classes took place long ago, so I would appreciate any help!

Comment: Is led a point source or a spherical one?

Comment: You can take it as a point source, since in reality we will be far away from the LED as compared to the size of the LED (1mm by 1mm surface). No spherical lens or other above the LED surface

Answer (score 0):

[image: flussoLED]

First of all, to avoid misunderstandings, let us set some definitions according to SI terms [(re. e.g. to this Wikipedia  article)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radiant_flux)

- *Radiant Flux (or Power)* ($W$): radiant energy per unit time
- *Radiant Intensity* ($W/{sr}$): radiant flux per solid angle
- *Irradiance (Flux density)* ($W/m^2$): radiant flux per unit area

For a point-like source, the power irradiated within a cone with vertex in the source will be constant,
and the Irradiance therefore will decrease with the square of the distance from the source.
Or equivalently, the power emitted within a steradiant (Intensity) is constant.
Now if you have a diagram (normally given in polar form) of the relative Intensity,
that shall mean that the total power irradiated by the led is given by the following integral for $\phi$ ranging from $0$ to $\pi /2$.
$$
\begin{gathered}
  P = \int_{\;0}^{\,\pi /2} {I_0 (R)I_r (\phi )\,2\pi R\sin \phi \,R\,d\phi }  =  \hfill \\
   = I_0 (R)\,2\pi R^{\,2} \int_{\;0}^{\,\pi /2} {I_r (\phi )\,\sin \phi \,d\phi }  =  \hfill \\
   = P_0 \;\int_{\;0}^{\,\pi /2} {I_r (\phi )\,\sin \phi \,d\phi }  \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered} 
$$
where $P_0$ is the power of the led if it was radiating with a constant flux 
equal to that in the vertical, i.e. with $I_r (\phi)=1$.
Otherwise, knowing $P$, then $P_0$ will represent a scale constant.

That premised,  the sketch above shows clearly that
the power emitted inside the solid conic angle of aperture $d\alpha$, which is $P_0 \;I_r (\phi )\,\sin \phi \,d\phi $,
on the plane at distance $h$ will distribute over a surface of $2\,\pi \,\rho (\phi )\,\,d\rho (\phi )$.
Since we have the following relations:
$$
\left\{ \begin{gathered}
  \rho  = h\;\tan \phi  \hfill \\
  d\rho  = \frac{h}
{{\cos ^{\,2} \phi }}\;d\phi  \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right.\quad  \Leftrightarrow \quad \left\{ \begin{gathered}
  \phi  = \arctan \left( {\rho /h} \right) \hfill \\
  d\phi  = \frac{{\cos ^{\,2} \phi }}
{h}d\rho  = \frac{h}
{{\left( {h^{\,2}  + \rho ^{\,2} } \right)}}d\rho  \hfill \\
  \sin \phi  = \frac{\rho }
{{\sqrt {h^{\,2}  + \rho ^{\,2} } }} \hfill \\
  \; \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right.
$$
the relative Irradiance (irradiance per 1 totally emitted W)  on the plane surface will be:

- in terms of $\phi$ and $h$

  > $$
  > Q (\phi ,h) = I_r (\phi )\,\frac{{\sin \phi \,d\phi }}
  > {{2\,\pi \,\rho (\phi )\,\,d\rho (\phi )}} = I_r (\phi )\,\frac{{\cos ^{\,3} \phi }}
  > {{2\,\pi \,h^{\,2} }}
  > $$
- in terms of $\rho$ and $h$

  > $$
  > Q (\rho ,h) = I_r \left( {\arctan \left( {\rho /h} \right)} \right)\,\frac{{\frac{\rho }
  > {{\sqrt {h^{\,2}  + \rho ^{\,2} } }}\,\frac{h}
  > {{\left( {h^{\,2}  + \rho ^{\,2} } \right)}}d\rho }}
  > {{2\,\pi \,\rho \,\,d\rho }} = I_r \left( {\arctan \left( {\rho /h} \right)} \right)\frac{1}
  > {{2\,\pi h^{\,2} \left( {1 + \left( {\rho /h} \right)^{\,2} } \right)^{\,3/2} }}\,
  > $$

The above relative Irradiance shall be then multiplicated by $P_0=I_0(R) 2 \pi R^2$ in order to get the value in 
$W/m^2$. 
Note that $I_0(R)=Q(0,R)$ as should be expected.